# I am trying to extract a values from column in postgressql with python. But i always get this error :

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

Type Error Boolean value of this clause is not define 
My Code Snippet for retrieving:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import text

connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="admin",
                              host="localhost",
                              port="5432",
                              database="myDB")

db = connection.cursor()
query = text("""
     SELECT input, input_type, value, output
     FROM value_rules
 """)
result = db.execute(query).fetchone()
print(result)
```

I dont understand its a simple query, i dont know what wrong i am doing.

[image: Check Image]

Comment: That error does not come from this code.

Comment: There is something strange. The error mentions is sqlachemy, but the code, that you show doesn't seem to involve sqlalchemy.

Can please create a full example (imports included) that's running and producing the error.
Of course we can't reproduce it without the database, but at least we know there is no important line missing.

Comment: @gelonida thankyou for your response .. sure i am adding imports also .. hold on

Comment: @gelonida please check it. i've added imports

Comment: Though your above code imports now sqlachemy no sqlalchemy function is called, So it should be impossible to get an error message from `sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py`

Are you 100% sure, that calling above code provokes the error that you mention?
You should be able to remove the line `from sqlalchemy import text` as you do not seem to use `text`

Comment: @gelonida yes. this is complete code. i am connecting db with psycopg2 . is that okay ?

Comment: ```@gelonida if i remove sqlachelemy import```,  but below i am using query = text . which is import from ```sqlalchemy```

Comment: ouch sorry I overlooked that one.
Never used sqlalchemy's text. Perhaps you don't use it as it is supposed to be called. Will try to skim through the doc.

Comment: in your simplified example the code should work if you just remove text() and pass the string directly to `db.execute()`

I'm no sqlalchemy specialist, but you shouldn't have to call sqlalchemy code to execute plain psycopg queries.

Comment: @gelonida it is throwing None output without using text from sqlalchemey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that `db.execute` does not understand clearly how to handle objects of type " `.TextClause` clause, representing a textual SQL string directly" - from the text() docs from the sqlalchemy.text() method call.

Changing the argument to .execute() from text object to normal string works as expected, change to

```
...
query = """
     SELECT input, input_type, value, output
     FROM value_rules
 """
 ...
```

Comment: As per stackoverflow ask help section guidelines, if this is the answer that works for you,  consider marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> result = db.execute(query).fetchone()
>
> it is throwing None output without using text from sqlalchemey

I find this hard to believe.

db.execute() returns None.  It does not return itself, so you can't chain calls like that.  None does not have a method named 'fetchone'.  So you will get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'`.  That is not the same thing as "None output".

The only thing using "text" from sqlalchemy does for you is throw a different error before you get a chance to stumble over the real error.

If you do it like this:

```
db.execute(query)
result = db.fetchone()
print(result)
```

and then get an output of the word 'None' (not an error referring to None), that means the database table is empty.